# How to handle a changed Library opened with dlopen()

Tags: c++, linux, dll, dlopen

I'm using a shared object in my program which is loaded via dlopen().
When I overwrite the library with `mv debug/newLibrary.so plugin/usedLibrary.so` my program crashes as soon as it tries to interact with the loaded library. I cant even use dlclose(), this gets me a SIGSEV.

What is the best way to handle with this situations?

OS is Linux

Edit: actual code

```
void DynamicallyLoadedLibrary::loadLibrary() {
    // ModificationTime updaten
    lastModificationTime = modificationTime();

    // Library laden
    libraryHandle = dlopen(path.c_str(), RTLD_NOW);

    if (!libraryHandle) { // Library gefunden?
        throw DynamicLibraryException("Dynamic Library not found: " + path + "\n" + dlerror());
    }

    // Funktion laden
    externalFunction = (dll_function) dlsym(libraryHandle, "run");

    char *error;
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) { // Funktion gefunden?
        throw DynamicLibraryException("Dynamic Library not found: run()\n" + string(error));
    }
}

void DynamicallyLoadedLibrary::close() {
    if (libraryHandle != nullptr) {
        cout << "DLL/close(): " << dlclose(libraryHandle) << endl; // DEBUG
        libraryHandle = nullptr;
        externalFunction = nullptr;
    }
}

void DynamicallyLoadedLibrary::operator()(vector<shared_ptr<ServerData>> &data) {
    // Wenn Datei sich geaendert hat, neu laden
    if (fileChanged()) {
        close();
        loadLibrary();
    }

    externalFunction(data);
}
```

Edit 2: The Library (UA_String is from `open62541`)
Its simply build with eclipse and copied in [...]/plugins. Execution works fine until I overwrite it

```
extern "C" void run(vector<shared_ptr<ServerData>> &data) {
    cout << "++++ OPC_WORKING_PACKAGE EXTERN ++++" << endl; // XXX
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        UA_String *uaString = (UA_String*) data[i]->dataReference();
        cout << string((char*) uaString->data, uaString->length) << endl;
    }
    cout << "---- OPC_WORKING_PACKAGE EXTERN ----" << endl; // XXX
}
```

Comment: Show actual code with a real example, that is an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). IIRC, it should work.

Comment: Done editing (above)

Comment: Show also parts of the build procedure which is producing (& installing) your plugin

Comment: Also done, its nothing special

Comment: But it is doing things wrongly.

Comment: don't overwrite the library (actually, it should fail with errno=EBUSY). Do this: `cp debug/newLibrary.so plugin/usedLibrary.so_new; ln -f usedLibrary.so_new plugin/usedLibrary.so; rm plugin/usedLibrary.so_new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

If you have some `/tmp/plugin.so` and you do

```
void* dl = dlopen("/tmp/plugin.so", TRL_NOW);
```

and later (in the *same* process) some

```
rename("/tmp/plugin.so", "/tmp/oldplugin.so")
```

(or even `unlink("/tmp/plugin.so");` ...) you should be able to `dlclose(dl);`

However, if your build process is making a new one, e.g. you have some `make /tmp/plugin.so` target, then you really should do a

```
 mv /tmp/plugin.so /tmp/plugin.so~
```

or even

```
 rm /tmp/plugin.so
```

*before* linking the shared library, e.g. before

```
gcc -shared -Wall -O /tmp/plugin*.pic.o -o /tmp/plugin.so
```

In other words, be sure that your build procedure is not overwriting bytes in the *same* [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (of the original `/tmp/plugin.so`)

So if you overwrite your old `/tmp/plugin.so` with some `mv /tmp/newplugin.so /tmp/plugin.so` command in your build process you'll better do a `mv /tmp/plugin.so /tmp/plugin.so~` or a `rm /tmp/plugin.so` just before.

Notice that [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (internally invoked by [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)) is actually working on opened inodes. See [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html). So you could [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) your shared library while still having it `dlopen`-ed.

So never overwrite bytes in an existing shared library *inode*; do whatever is necessary to be sure to create a *fresh* shared library *inode* in your plugin build procedure.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](https://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf) & Drepper's [How to Write a Shared Library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

BTW, the real issue is not related to `dlopen` but to the nature of [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (that is, of opened inodes) on POSIX systems (on which several processes can read and write the same file; the user or sysadmin -or tool developer- is supposed to avoid breaking havoc.).

Use also [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) (as `pmap 1234`) and/or `cat /proc/1234/maps` to understand the memory mapping of [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) of pid 1234 (i.e. its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)).

In practice, the user or sysadmin installing a plugin should ensure that a pristine inode is created for it, or that no process is using that plugin (before installation). It is his responsibility (and is a whole system issue). So you really need to educate your user or sysadmin, and document the issue, e.g. by suggesting the use of [install(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html) and/or locking utilities like [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) when installing plugins.

PS. Copying in a private copy the shared object before `dlopen` might improve the situation, but does not solve the issue (what if the shared object source gets updated during the copy?). The real bug is in the build process which overwrites a shared object instead of writing & creating a pristine new inode.

Comment: no, its not renamed in the program. The Program is running and Im overwriting the library extern with `mv [...]/debug/newLibrary.so [...]/plugin/myLibrary.so`

Comment: And that is wrong. You should `rm [...]/plugin/myLibrary.so` or at least `mv  [...]/plugin/myLibrary.so  [...]/plugin/myLibrary.so~` *before* your `mv [...]/debug/newLibrary.so [...]/plugin/myLibrary.so`.

Comment: Okay, it may be a better way to copy the file. But what if another one does it this way? I'm just writing the program, Im not the one managing the server later days and I need to handle with those errors

Comment: @Narase Make a copy of the library. Then `dlopen` that copy. Then `rm` it as soon  as the `dlopen` succeeds.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. Making a temporarily copy seems like a working way. Also thanks for the lots of links Basile

Comment: No, the temporary copy is not a reliable way to solve the issue.

Comment: can you tell me why not?

Comment: I explained in my answer. What if the sysadmin is building & installing the plugin while you are copying it (in several pieces)?

Comment: But thats not in my hand, I cant tell the admin "hey, do it this way", well... sure I can, but what if he decides not to do as told?

Comment: The mistake is his own. BTW, it is not related to shared objects. If you are running a large application (e.g. libreoffice or gcc) and are overwriting (in some other shell) without care the executable it is running, you are likely to crash it also. Practically speaking `ETXTBSY` (in [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)...) is nearly obsolete.